# Is a software to emulate the macOS finder available for Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, finder

Is there any way to make Windows Explorer, or software the emulates, the columned file exploring system in the macOS “Finder?”

[image: Mac OS Finder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough to me, people like this...

There are some software solutions to do similar things. I am not sure exactly the features you want, but [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/download.htm) seems to have a strong fan base for many years.

Comment: its close but the mac osx has an added preview pane. I have tens of thousands of photos to sort through and a columned explorer window has been the best and quickest way so far. I have sort of emulated it by opening several windows in columns - but sifting through so many folders is making the task very tedious. Image sorting programs are useless even the flag ship Bridge is awful!

Comment: @AasimAzam FYI you can enable a preview pane in Windows (7) Explorer, you won't get the multi column navigation but at least you can see your images, does this help?

Comment: its what I am doing, but I need the easy file navigation to make it more streamline

Comment: I don't see how that is more streamlined to be honest. Windows 7 Breadcrumb approach seems better... buyt if you need a preview Total Commander seems to be a good approach...